# Pass a php variable to a jQuery function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have searched and tried several different methods to pass a php $variable to a jQuery function. I can pass a string simply by using myfunction("Hello");. But if I try myfunction(); or myfunction($variable); with or without quotes it fails to run.

```
function wholesection(val) {
    $("#whole-section").slideUp("fast", function () {
    });
    $('#label-cemetery').text("Section*");
    $('#poc').val(val);
}
```

The above works if I send a literal string enclosed in double quotes, using:

```
    <?php
        echo '<script>',
         'wholesection("Hello");',
         '</script>'
        ;
    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $variable = "Hello";

        echo '<script>',
        'wholesection(' . $variable . ');',
        '</script>'
        ;
    ?>
```

Or other similar variants do not work.

```
'wholesection($variable);',
'wholesection("$variable");',
```

Comment: You can call like this `<script>wholesection('<?=phpVariable?>');</script>`

Comment: Don't you see difference between `"Hello"` and `$variable`?>

Comment: use like this you are missing quations echo `'<script>' . wholesection($variable). '</script>';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your `$variable` has value `"Hello"`.

Then this code:

```
echo 'wholesection('.$variable.');',
```

is rendrered in html like

```
wholesection(Hello);
```

See? You're passing `Hello` to a function. Not `"Hello"` but `Hello`. 
And `Hello` is considered a javascript variable. I bet you don't have it.

So, the fix is - add quotes:

```
echo 'wholesection("'.$variable.'");',
```

which will be rendered as:

```
wholesection("Hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can pass it by echoing your php varriable in the script**

try below code :

```
<?php
    $variable = "Hello";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var simple = '<?php echo $variable; ?>';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
$variable = "Hello";

if(true){
 ?>
 <script>
  wholesection("<?php echo $variable?>");
 </script>
 <?
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you all, that was all I needed - a fresh set of eyes & an unfogged brain.